# Removing code duplication in inheritance?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, inheritance, polymorphism

I have wrote the following code:

```
std::shared_ptr<mtm::Character>
Game::makeCharacter(CharacterType type, Team team, units_t health, units_t ammo, units_t range, units_t power) {
    if (health <= 0 || ammo < 0 || range < 0 || power < 0)
    {
        throw mtm::IllegalArgument();
    }
    std::shared_ptr<Character> out = nullptr;
    if (type == SOLDIER)
    {
        out = std::shared_ptr<Character>(new mtm::Soldier(team, health, ammo, range, power));
    }
    if (type == MEDIC)
    {
        out = std::shared_ptr<Character>(new mtm::Medic(team, health, ammo, range, power));
    }
    return out;
}
```

As you can see I have some kind of code duplication, what if there are 100 types... I would have to write 100 if statements which doesn't sound the perfect way to do it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not easy to give a suggestion here, because it is not clear how `CharacterType type` is determined when `makeCharacter` is called. You might be able to change `CharacterType` to a template argument, but this might just move those `if` clauses to another place. If you have those `CharacterType type` to class mappings at multiple places, then you could generalize that by template specialization, so that you don't need that `if` clauses at multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a function template:

```
template<typename C>
std::shared_ptr<mtm::Character>
Game::makeCharacter(Team team, units_t health, units_t ammo, units_t range, units_t power) {
    if (health <= 0 || ammo < 0 || range < 0 || power < 0)
    {
        throw mtm::IllegalArgument();
    }
    return std::make_shared<C>(team, health, ammo, range, power);
}
```

And call it:

```
auto res = Game::makeCharacter<Soldier>(t, h, a, r, p);
```

Comment: What's the difference between than and simply `auto res = make_shared<Soldier>(t,h,a,r,p)`?

Comment: @MikaelH There's validation in `makeCharacter` that you'd miss if you do it directly.

Comment: @MikaelH how would you pick the right subclass then?

Comment: OP still needs the same list of switches to map the enum to the types, but I guess thats as good as it can get

Comment: That's a good point @idclev463035818. `auto res` would force derived class type, which is probably not what's wanted.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks, but what if I want to call it like this: Game::makeCharacter(CharacterType::MEDIC, Team::CPP, 10, 2, ...)

Comment: @BigSur you need to map the enum to the types somewhere. I would not worry too much about code duplication in a factory function, because typically thats the only palce where you need to switch for each type.

Comment: actually with this OPs function would not look that different. This just replaces each line `out = std::shared_ptr<Character>(new mtm::Soldier(team, health, ammo, range, power));` with `out = Game::makeCharacter<Soldier>(t, h, a, r, p);`. Not a big win, or do I miss something?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Nah, perhaps not. I still has the validation part though.

Comment: @BigSur You can move the code duplication somewhere else: https://godbolt.org/z/QCWaNM. I guess any day is a good day to start exercising type traits.

Comment: @MikaelH That's a nice approach if one wants to keep the enums. I [added a deduction guide](https://godbolt.org/z/LKSgnm) too it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Technically, that's not a deduction guide, but a helper alias template :) . But yeah, it makes it more readable. Deduction guides: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

Comment: @MikaelH Indeed. I got confused :)

Answer (score 1):

As @idclev noted in a comment, if you want to map from enumeration to type, you need some code somewhere to...map from enumeration to type.

You can, however, change how the code is distributed, and some people find the re-distributed version more to their liking.

For one obvious example, you can include the actual creation code as a `static` member of each class. Then you register a class for creation by the factory by passing the enumeration value and the address of the creation function for that class to the factory:

```
class Soldier : public Character {
    // ...
    static std::shared_ptr<Character> create(int t, int h, int a, int r, int p) { 
        return std::make_shared<Soldier>(t, h, a, r, p);
    }
};

class Medic {
    // ...
    static std::shared_ptr<Character> create(int t, int h, int a, int r, int p) {
       return std::make_shared<Medic>(t, h, a, r, p);
    }
};

class Factory {
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Character>(*creator)(int, int, int, int, int);

    std::map<int, creator> creators;

public:
    void register(int value, creator c) { 
        creators[value] = c;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Character> create(int type, int t, int h, int a, int r, int p) { 
        auto creator = creators.find(type);
        if (creator == creators.end()) {
            throw std::logic_error("Unknown character type");
        }
        return (creator->second)(t, h, a, r, p);
    }
};
```

So, you still have essentially the same duplicated code (i.e., each class still needs a `create` function to create a character of that type), but it's part of each class instead of all being crammed into the factory. On the other hand, it also adds a little bit of extra code as well, to register each derived class with the factory. In exchange for that, you do at least get away from the giant switch on type, which can be pretty painful when it gets large (e.g., with 100 cases, even just finding one you care about can start to become somewhat painful.

This design can also be particularly useful for dealing with things like downloadable content. With the switch statement, the structure of the code in the factory reflects all the character types in the system. With a data driven factory, it's a bit easier to find a DLL/.so, load it, and call an appropriate function to register it with the system to add a new character type.